# VBA Excel: create graphs for unique values from flexible ranges for multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, graph

This puzzle is getting on my nerves now, as a beginning VBA Excel user with a lot of ambition to automize things... (Maybe a bit too ambitious :) )

The things I've managed this far are: creating a new file with a worksheet for every company, containing all current available data.
A control sheet where I can select which stakeholder should receive which sheet(s), with which text and when. 
This all works fine but I want to add graphs to the data to show what's going on over time.

The problem is:
- looping through a variable set of data every month there's a new column added so the range of columns should be flexible.
- the number of rows per company isn't predefined and may vary month-over-month
- the number of companies where a worksheet is created for may vary as well

My intention is to:
- create graphs for each unique value in Column D
- name the graphs (title) with the unique value in column D
- name the new created tab with the name of the Company in column A (let's say: 'Company A - graphs' as a sheet name)
- include all graphs from the current sheet in one sheet (the information on the current sheet is of ONE company)
- go to the next sheet and do the same (loop) until all sheets are done
- add another sheet with all sheet names that are currently in the file (existing + created)
- the label of the Y-values is in column G ('Name')
- the Y-values are in the columns H and further and row 2 and all the way down (flexible)
- the headers are in row 1 --> only the months (H >>) should be included on the X-axis
- So the information in the columns A:F shouldn't be used other than mentioned above

I got quite a piece of script but I'm on a dead end street. Any help would be very much appreciated!

If you have any questions please let me know.

Many many thanks in advance!

Wouter :-)

P.S.: Here's the file: http://we.tl/786d6b6cs0

```
Sub WJS_CreateGraphs()


Response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to create graphs for all worksheets?",     vbYesNo, "Graph Creator")
If Response = vbNo Then
Exit Sub
End If


' ------------------------------------ Now we will create pivot tables for all scenario's

Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim C As Integer

' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active workbook.

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

' Begin the loop.
For C = 1 To WS_Count


Dim I As Integer
Dim selecta As Range
Dim grFilter As Range, grUniques As Range
Dim grCell As Range, grCounter As Integer
Dim arow As Integer
Dim acol As Integer
Dim StartPoint As Integer
Dim EndPoint As Integer
Dim rStartPoint As Integer
Dim rEndPoint As Integer


ActiveSheet.Range("D1").Select
Set selecta = Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
Set grFilter = Range("D1", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))


 With grFilter

    ' Filter column A to show only one of each item (uniques) in column A
    .AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

    ' Set a variable to the Unique values
    Set grUniques = Range("D2", Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


' Filter, Copy, and Paste each unique to its' own sheet in the new workbook
For Each cell In grUniques

    counter = counter + 1

    'NOTE - this filter is on column D(field:=1), to change
    'to a different column you need to change the field number relative to the Unique Value range above
    grFilter.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value

'********************************************************************************************************************************


    temp_StartPoint = 2
    temp_EndPoint = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count



For arow = temp_StartPoint To temp_EndPoint



    StartPoint = 2
    EndPoint = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    FirstColumn = 7
    LastColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    ' remember the sheet to return to, this is the current active sheet --> after creating a graph VBA will return to this sheet
    MyPrevSheet = ActiveSheet.name

    Charts.Add

    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine 'Type of graph

' Return to previous sheet
        If Len(MyPrevSheet) > 0 Then
    Sheets(MyPrevSheet).Activate
Else
    MsgBox "You have not switched sheets yet since opening the file!"
End If

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Cells(StartPoint, FirstColumn) & ":" & Cells(EndPoint, LastColumn))
    ', PlotBy:=xlRows 'data source
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = ActiveSheets.Range(FirstColumn & "1:" & Cells(LastColumn, 1))
    'naming the x-axis
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).name = "Spwr" ' Name of 1st data series 1
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    On Error Resume Next

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1) 'put labels on 1st data series
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "##"
    End With

    With ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue)
        .HasMajorGridlines = False
        .HasMinorGridlines = False
    End With
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select ' Background of graph
    With Selection.Border
        .ColorIndex = 16
        .Weight = xlThin
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
    Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).name = "salespower"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = ActiveSheets.Range("G2:m2")

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2) 'put labels on 2nd line
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "##"
    End With

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).name = "Tests"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = ActiveSheets.Range("G2:m2")

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3) 'put labels on 3rd line
        .HasDataLabels = True
        .DataLabels.NumberFormat = "##"
    End With


    ActiveChart.Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ChartTitle = "Naam van de chart"

Next arow

Next cell

rngFilter.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'***********************************************************************************************************************************************

End With


Next C

End Sub
```